# how do i create a tab menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to this site but I've visited it before for information
I also use w3school for information but I cant seem to get it done.
I am trying to create a tab menu with the use of CSS, JavaScript, and HTML.
The CSS is used for creating the sizes of the buttons as well as the pictures and the information on the screen. but my problem is with the JavaScript part.
I want a tab menu with 4 tabs. I have managed to get the 4 buttons for the tabs as well as the HTML `onclick` part but the problem is that when I click on a tab button it doesn't hide the current open tab and show the new tab info

this is what I have in the HTML

```
<div class="dashmenu1" onclick="menu1()"></div>
<div class="dashboardmenu1"></div>
        
<!-- Dashboard Menu 2 -->
<div class="dashmenu2" onclick="menu2()"></div>
<div class="dashboardmenu2"></div>
        
<!-- Dashboard Menu 3 -->
<div class="dashmenu3" onclick="menu3()"></div>
<div class="dashboardmenu3"></div>
        
<!-- Dashboard Menu 4 -->
<div class="dashmenu4" onclick="menu4()"></div>
<div class="dashboardmenu4"></div>
```

the dashmenu is the button that is programmed in the CSS whereas the dashboardmenu is the background image in the CSS

I have no clue what I have to do in javascript to make the dashboardmenu disappear and show the new dashboardmenu

this is what I have in CSS

```
.dashmenu1 {
    z-index: 70;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 717px;
    top: 156px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 65px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dashmenu1.yes {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
    transition-delay: 4s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.dashboardmenu1 {
    z-index: 10;
    background-image: url("images/infodashmenu01.png");
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1723px;
    height: 777px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.dashboardmenu1.yes {
    opacity: 1;
}


/* dashboard menu 2 */
.dashmenu2 {
    z-index: 70;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 798px;
    top: 156px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 65px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dashmenu2.yes {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
    transition-delay: 4s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.dashboardmenu2 {
    z-index: 20;
    background-image: url("images/infodashmenu02.png");
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1723px;
    height: 777px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.dashboardmenu2.yes {
    opacity: 1;
}


/* dashboard menu 3 */
.dashmenu3 {
    z-index: 70;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 880px;
    top: 156px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 65px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dashmenu3.yes {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
    transition-delay: 4s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.dashboardmenu3 {
    z-index: 30;
    background-image: url("images/infodashmenu03.png");
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1723px;
    height: 777px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.dashboardmenu3.yes {
    opacity: 1;
}


/* dashboard menu 4 */
.dashmenu4 {
    z-index: 70;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 961px;
    top: 156px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 65px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dashmenu4.yes {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
    transition-delay: 4s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.dashboardmenu4 {
    z-index: 40;
    background-image: url("images/infodashmenu04.png");
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1723px;
    height: 777px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.dashboardmenu4.yes {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

this is what i have in the JS
it's not done since i can't figure out the other parts

```
function menu1(dispId, dispValue) {
var dispId = "menu1";
    if (sessionStorage.menu1 == undefined) {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu1 == "Off" || sessionStorage.menu1 == "On") {
        var dispValue = sessionStorage.menu1.value;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.menu1 == "Off") {
        var dispValue = "On";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu1 == "On") {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    }
}

function menu2(dispId, dispValue) {
var dispId = "menu2";
    if (sessionStorage.menu2 == undefined) {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu2 == "Off" || sessionStorage.menu2 == "On") {
        var dispValue = sessionStorage.menu2.value;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.menu2 == "Off") {
        var dispValue = "On";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu2 == "On") {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    }
}

function menu3(dispId, dispValue) {
var dispId = "menu3";
    if (sessionStorage.menu3 == undefined) {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu3 == "Off" || sessionStorage.menu3 == "On") {
        var dispValue = sessionStorage.menu3.value;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.menu3 == "Off") {
        var dispValue = "On";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu3 == "On") {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    }
}

function menu4(dispId, dispValue) {
var dispId = "menu4";
    if (sessionStorage.menu4 == undefined) {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu4 == "Off" || sessionStorage.menu4 == "On") {
        var dispValue = sessionStorage.menu4.value;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.menu4 == "Off") {
        var dispValue = "On";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    } else if (sessionStorage.menu4 == "On") {
        var dispValue = "Off";
        sessionStorage.setItem(dispId, dispValue);
    }
}
```

maybe this helps. each button on the tab is a button without text or image. the background skin shows the buttons and when clicked on the button the popup shows the active button.

i changed the JS code to

```
function menu1() {
    $('.dashboardmenu1').css({"visibility" : "visible"});
    $('.dashboardmenu2').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu3').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu4').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
}

function menu2() {
    $('.dashboardmenu1').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu2').css({"visibility" : "visible"});
    $('.dashboardmenu3').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu4').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
}
function menu3() {
    $('.dashboardmenu1').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu2').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu3').css({"visibility" : "visible"});
    $('.dashboardmenu4').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
}

function menu4() {
    $('.dashboardmenu1').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu2').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu3').css({"visibility" : "hidden"});
    $('.dashboardmenu4').css({"visibility" : "visible"});
}
```

and it works like i wanted it to

Comment: The html part is missing

Comment: show your js, pls

Comment: no need to write a unique function for each tab. in your case, you can use the `forEach()` method, which will significantly reduce your js code.

Answer (score 0):

that's what you need?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const menuButton = e.target.closest('.menu-button');
  
  if (!menuButton) return;
  
  const menuName = menuButton.getAttribute('data-name');

  if (!menuName) return;
  
  const menu = document.querySelector(`.menu[data-name="${menuName}"]`);
  
  if (!menu) return;
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu').forEach((menu) => menu.classList.remove('active'));
  
  menu.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" data-name="1">#1</div>
<div class="menu" data-name="2">#2</div>
<div class="menu" data-name="3">#3</div>
<div class="menu" data-name="4">#4</div>

<button class="menu-button" data-name="1">Menu #1</button>
<button class="menu-button" data-name="2">Menu #2</button>
<button class="menu-button" data-name="3">Menu #3</button>
<button class="menu-button" data-name="4">Menu #4</button>
```

Comment: i'll try that and see what it does

Comment: edit: i tried the code but it just disappears behind the page background. adding a `z-indez` doesn't help either

Comment: @SergeantWeijand, I haven't seen your attempts, so I can't help

Comment: @SergeantWeijand, if this answer helped you, then you can check the box of arrow to the left of it